# How to Debug.log or print to screen?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm training on a Unity tutorial, but where the teacher is editing the code with MonoDevelop, I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

He's entered code such as these:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;   
using UnityEngine;
   [snip]
Debug.log("Hello World");
print ("Hello World");
```

...but the last two lines don't work when I enter them. The most significant clue is that Intellisense doesn't start typing "Debug" or "Print" for me.

Am I missing some way to activate them, or is there a different way to accomplish this in Visual Studio?

And would installing MonoDevelop solve the issue?

EDIT:

I didn't think I needed to show the "[snip]" code, but that was presumptuous. Here's the whole thing:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;   //This is not in the tutorial's version
using UnityEngine;

public class HelloWorld : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        string name = "Shawn V. Wilson";
        int age = 39;
        float speed = 4.3f;
        bool likes = false;
        var stringArray = new string[2];
        stringArray[0] = "hello";
        stringArray[1] = "world";

        var phrase = stringArray[0] + " " + stringArray[1];
     
       //print[phrase];     Ignoring this for now
       debug.log[phrase];

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        
    }
}
```

In Unity, the error I get is:

```
error CS0103: The name 'debug' does not exist in the current context
```

...but before I even get to Unity, the debug command is not recognized by VS. (It doesn't appear in the type-ahead, and shouldn't it make it capitalized?)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code, nor does it have anything to do with your editor. A few things that you may want to check, ¿Where are you putting those prints, is that part of the code being called? try putting that on the `Start` method ¿Are you attaching the script to any game object? ¿Are you checking unity's console or the editor's console? Those logs will show up in unity, not in visual studio.

Comment: Is the code in your question an exact copy of what you're using in your script? If so then it is because the logs are not inside a class and a function. if it isn't an exact copy of your code, then please edit your answer to reflect your code correctly. Else we won't be able to help much.

Comment: Please add your exact complete code .. also: Is your script attached to a `GameObject` in the scene? Anyway it is unclear if you want to use `Debug.Log` or rather an answer to the question `How to print a log on Screen?` since `Debug.Log` or `print` also print to the Console... you would need a `Text` component to print to the screen ...

Comment: Monodevelop was given up on. Although you could use notepad visual studio is the recommended, code works but is temperamental and raider is another good one.

Comment: It is [`Debug.Log`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.Log.html) **Capital `D`** and **Capital `L`** ! c# is case sensitive and I would close this question as typo based then ... It is already causing enough confusion and low quality answers ...

Comment: derHugo - Changing it to upper case does stop the error, which is the important thing. But it still doesn't appear in Intellisense. Do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell what the problem is from your code, but from what i see you are not calling the print function, even more so it shouldnt let you run the code.

if you want it to be called when you run the application put your code in

```
void Start()
{
print("Hello World");
}
```

if you want it to run every frame put it in

```
void Update()
{
print("Hello World");
}
```

or just create a custom function

```
private void MyFunction()
{
print("Hello");
}
```

and call it whenever you want..

i hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

For the intelli sense for VS, you can turn on it in "Edit -> Intelli Sense" or just install the newest/older version of VS.

For example you could install VS 2015/2019 Community Edition, that is the fastest way.

Comment: What I should have said was that Intellisense recognizes everything *except* Debug and Print.

Answer (score -2):

Your two lines of code are not in any function.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

void Start ()
{
    Debug.log("Hello World");
    print ("Hello World");
}
```

There are functions such as the Start or Update function that are called automatically, such as the start function or the update function. The start function is called as soon as the script is run for the first time, so it is only called once. The update function is called every frame.

Comment: A method can also not exist outside of a type. You probably want to wrap this in a `class` of type `MonoBehaviour` ...